# How to use the variable in upload (from train) method , to predict method?

Tags: python, flask, scikit-learn

Please help me! I got some error. I try to train data from the request file. But, when I try to predict, I got the error, how to use the variable in upload (from train) method , to predict method (make the variable text_clf share scope between upload and predict)? and how if I not upload(train) from the upload file, I still use the dataset previously?

This is the code

```
@app.route('/upload', methods=['GET','POST'])
def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        df = pd.read_csv(file)
        df['label'] = df['label'].map({'HS': 0, 'Non_HS': 1})
        X = df['clean']
        y = df['label']

        from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
        X = X.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)
        y = y.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)
        X = X.dropna()
        y = y.dropna()
        X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

        from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
        from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
        from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
        text_clf = Pipeline([('tfidf',TfidfVectorizer()),('clf',LinearSVC())])
        text_clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
        joblib.dump(text_clf, 'SVM_model.pkl')
        return redirect(url_for('upload', file=file))
    return render_template('upload_data.html')

@app.route('/predict',methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    #df = pd.read_csv('Dataset/preprocess1109v2.csv', encoding="latin-1")
    # Features and Labels
    SVM_model = open('SVM_model.pkl','rb')
    text_clf = joblib.load(SVM_model)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        message = request.form['message']
        data = [message]
        #vect = count_vect.transform(data).toarray()
        my_prediction = text_clf.predict(data)

    return render_template('classification.html',prediction = my_prediction)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not understand your intention to make predictions with the same file that was used in the training and testing phase. But it is common to save the model in a file after training, and when using the model, load it again

see: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html

Comment: Here, I just learn from tutorial. In that code he/she made that code in same file. I just improve to read / train from upload file.

Okay, later I will make another file, but firstly I want this work. hehe.

Comment: Thank you. This Solved with it.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, your variable `text_clf` is created at the `upload()` function, so the scope is only for that function. In the `predict()` function the `text_clf` variable cannot be accessed.

Try importing flask, setting the text_clf variable to `flask.g` and then retrieve it using `flask.g.get()`:

```
from flask import *
@app.route('/upload', methods=['GET','POST'])
def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        df = pd.read_csv(file)
        df['label'] = df['label'].map({'HS': 0, 'Non_HS': 1})
        X = df['clean']
        y = df['label']

        from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
        X = X.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)
        y = y.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)
        X = X.dropna()
        y = y.dropna()
        X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

        from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
        from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
        from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
        text_clf = Pipeline([('tfidf',TfidfVectorizer()),('clf',LinearSVC())])
        text_clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
        g.x = text_clf
        return redirect(url_for('upload', file=file))
    return render_template('upload_data.html')

@app.route('/predict',methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    #df = pd.read_csv('Dataset/preprocess1109v2.csv', encoding="latin-1")
    # Features and Labels

    if request.method == 'POST':
        message = request.form['message']
        data = [message]
        #vect = count_vect.transform(data).toarray()
        text_clf = g.get('x', None)
        my_prediction = text_clf.predict(data)
    return render_template('classification.html',prediction = my_prediction)
```

EDIT: Also say that user @Jorge Luís Melgarejo answer is a better way to go, I am just giving a "workaround" solution for this specific problem.

Comment: I try this, it said "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'predict'"

Comment: I will try to see if i messed up with something later, maybe this can help you now https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.g